# UIWebView background colour change behind text

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have an `UIWebView`, where i changed the background image. but the image is not changed behind the  text,but displaying the image apart from the text. it just shows white background behind text, can any one let me know how can i remove it.

```
self.webview.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        self.webview.opaque = NO;
        UIColor *background=[[UIColor alloc]initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mainbg2_ipad.png"]];
        self.webview.backgroundColor=background;
        self.view.backgroundColor=background;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code...

```
self.webview.opaque = NO;  ///Set YES,just try it 
self.webview.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mainbg2_ipad.jpeg"]];
self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mainbg2_ipad.jpeg"]];
```

Comment: UIWebview its showing image where it is empty without text. but not showing image were the text is. it is showing white colour. – makumar 8 mins ago

Comment: @makumar webview will display a document, so background color is really nothing that makes a lot of sense here. If you want to display something while no page is loaded, build a placeholder page containing your background.

Comment: also try this [self.webview setOpaque:YES];
     self.webview.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

Comment: @makumar now its wroking dude??

Answer (score 0):

Comment this line: `self.webview.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];`  & then try.

Comment: UIWebview its showing image where it is empty without text. but not showing image were the text is. it is showing white colour.